# Unknown katana mei

Tags: translation, kanji

Can anybody translate this kanji I found on a katana I recently bought?

[image]

Comment: It seem this is the weapon series of 源善平、義朝.http://meitou.info/index.php/%E5%85%AB%E9%BE%8D

Answer (score 3):

「八龍刀」
A sword probably made in China.
The name means literally *eight dragons sword*.

[Here](http://sekaitouken.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-73.html) is another 八龍刀.

A famous Japanese old legendary talk of **Yamata no Orochi** or *8-branched giant snake* is right [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamata_no_Orochi), and in this article there is [a photograph of a sculpture](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A4%E3%83%9E%E3%82%BF%E3%83%8E%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AD%E3%83%81#/media/File:Sakaiminato_Mizuki_Shigeru_Road_Yamata_no_Orochi_Statue_1.jpg) of seemingly eight dragons, not eight giant snakes, but the legendary talk probably has nothing to do with the 八龍刀 *eight dragons sword* which is shown by the questioner.